# Order of execution of Tkinter mousePressed event

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

I have recently been trying to finish a project I started a few years ago, and on revisiting the problem, finally decided to seek help since I cannot figure out what is going on exactly.

The scenario is a game called Reversi, and I have created an algorithm (albeit not a very good one) for the computer. Now, when player A plays against the computer, I have written the order of execution to be as follows, upon mouse click event:

```
makeMove(canvas, row_clicked, column_clicked)
if canvas.data["computer"] and not canvas.data["noMove"]:
            #time.sleep(2)
            computerAI2(canvas)
```

makeMove makes a move and updates the main board (update: in tkinter, I delete the entire canvas [my board] then recreate the whole board). This works perfectly fine player to player, but when I include the computer, it seems to complete the updating all in one go, even though makeMove is (supposedly) completed before the computerAI2 starts its calls. computerAI2 also calls makeMove, so it should be updating after my mouseclick, and then once more after the computerAI2 finishes its algorithm.

But it doesn't. I have looked towards threading (note I haven't "actually" tried this, since I have never threaded before and seems difficult to implement and integrate in), towards adding time.sleep(), adding more pauses and phases in between to try and update the board before it gets to the computerAI2.

For absolute conviction that ordering is the problem, I tested by including

```
        makeMove(canvas, row_clicked, column_clicked)
        canvas.delete(ALL)

        if canvas.data["computer"] and not canvas.data["noMove"]:
            computerAI2(canvas)
```

And no response (same if placed above computerAI2 after the if). It just updates all in one go. Comparing to:

```
        makeMove(canvas, row_clicked, column_clicked)

        if canvas.data["computer"] and not canvas.data["noMove"]:
            computerAI2(canvas)
            canvas.delete(ALL)
```

Then this does delete everything after all is resolved, and I'm left with a blank slate (as expected). So the fact that it doesn't wipe everything inbetween... the fact is, I have some extra debugging inbetween that shows the computerAI2 is running (prints feedback) between my mouseclick and the eventual completion and update of the canvas/board. So it is not like it can't run and delays things in between, only for some odd reason refuses to reupdate the board in between!

```
def mousePressed(event):

    (... set up etc)

    makeMove(canvas, row_clicked, column_clicked)

        if canvas.data["computer"] and not canvas.data["noMove"]:
            computerAI2(canvas)
```

So my query is, what exactly is happening with the order here? Does it have something to do with the fact that its a mousePressed event?

This almost certainly, provided that the above information is not enough, requires looking at the source code to see how I am building the board through tkinter and the functions I call to. It is quite comprehensive to take it all in however. I am happy to share if someone is up to the task (it is clear if you know which parts to ignore and jump to the important sections). I will tell you the relevant functions that are being in use.

Thank you so much for your insights.

edit: the functions simplified for logic:

```
def makeMove(canvas, row, col):
    flipCounters(canvas, row, col)
    redrawAll(canvas)

def redrawAll(canvas): 
    canvas.delete(ALL)
    drawBoard(canvas)

def ComputerAI2(canvas)
    (the source of issue may be originating here, ie it may be nothing to do with order of execution, rather some error in the behaviour. However I have checked extensively here)
    algorithm --> makeMove(canvas, row, col)
```

edit2:

100% determined problem is not to do with computerAI2. It can only originate from makeMove, or really is some ordering problem to do with mousePressed Event.

```
makeMove(canvas, row_clicked, column_clicked)
if canvas.data["computer"] and not canvas.data["noMove"]:
        time.sleep(2)
        makeMove(canvas, 1,1)
```

The above STILL delays. Ie, it updates both moves at once, not update one move, wait 2 seconds, then updates the other move. 
However, 95% certain that makeMove is not the problem. If someone would create a quick mousePressed event in tkinter and test "print 1,2,3,4,5, time.sleep(5), print ok", if THAT doesn't delay, and works as 1,2,3,4,5ok all at once, then that resolves the root of the problem is with the mousePressed(event) problem. But how to FIX that, through threading?

edit3: Still no progress, havent managed to find the problem. If anyone could help I would really appreciate it, its a shame not to get such a nice project working.

edit4: Managed to google the solution out of luck, involves using "update" Haven't implemented yet but was from another thread answered by BryanOakley to do with running a function before the frame, "frame.update()" was the solution.

Comment: Are you really just asking "how can I have the computer do its move two seconds in the future"?

Comment: @BryanOakley I want my move to play out, then his move, not both at once. I do not see the problem in my code it is written in order of execution but it doesn't run as such. The computer does do its move two seconds in the future already, but it does mine along with it. It is a matter of aesthetics; the whole game works perfectly fine but it doesn't feel nice to see two move increments.